# Getting issue in screen recording and webcam together in js

Tags: javascript, media, webcam, recording

I have tried to record the screen and webcam but not getting stream data. I want to record screen and webcam recording and merge them and upload them to the server. I'm using a JS media recorder to record the screen and webcam.

```
function shareScreen()
        {
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
            
                "monitor",
                "window",
                "browser"
            
            var screenConstraints = { video: {
                displaySurface: "monitor",
            }, audio: true };

            navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(screenConstraints).then(function(screenStream)
            {
                let displaySurface = screenStream.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings().displaySurface;
                if (displaySurface !== 'monitor') 
                {
                    alert('Share your entire screen with audio to start your test');
                    location.reload();
                }

                var micConstraints = {audio:true};
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(micConstraints).then(function(micStream) {
    
                var composedStream = new MediaStream();

                screenStream.getVideoTracks().forEach(function(videoTrack) {
                    composedStream.addTrack(videoTrack);
                });

                var context = new AudioContext();

                var audioDestinationNode = context.createMediaStreamDestination();

                if (screenStream && screenStream.getAudioTracks().length > 0) {
                    const systemSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(screenStream);
                    const systemGain = context.createGain();
                    systemGain.gain.value = 1.0;
                    systemSource.connect(systemGain).connect(audioDestinationNode);
                }

                if (micStream && micStream.getAudioTracks().length > 0) {
                    const micSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(micStream);
                    const micGain = context.createGain();
                    micGain.gain.value = 1.0;
                    micSource.connect(micGain).connect(audioDestinationNode);
                }
                audioDestinationNode.stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(function(audioTrack) {
                    composedStream.addTrack(audioTrack);
                });

                localStream = composedStream;
            
                videoElement.srcObject = localStream;
                videoElement.play();
                videoElement.muted = true;
                // stopBtn.disabled = true;

                // start button functionality

                console.log('local stream '+ localStream);
                
                if (localStream != null) 
                {
                    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(localStream);
                    chunks = [];
                    mediaRecorder.start(60000); // number define the chunsks time duration
                    mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
                        chunks.push(event.data);
                    });
                    console.log('chunks data ' + chunks);
                    mediaRecorder.onstop = function() 
                    {
                        // web_cam_blob = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(chunks, { type: 'video/webm' }));
                        
                        var blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "video/webm" });
                        console.log('blob URL '+blob);
                        var videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        console.log('video URL '+videoURL);
                        const fd = new FormData();
                        chunks.forEach((chunk, index) => {
                            fd.append("video-blob", chunk, `chunk${index}.webm`);
                            fd.append("user_directory",'<?php echo $directory_name?>');
                            fd.append("username",'<?php echo $user_data['usersFirstname'].' '.$user_data['usersLastname']?>');
                            fd.append("userId", '<?php echo $userId?>');
                            fd.append('action','upload_chunks');
                            fetch('<?php echo APP_URL?>save.php', {method: "POST", body: fd})
                            .then(response => response.json())
                            .then(res => {
                              console.log('respone message '+ res.message);
                                if(res.status == true){
                                    fd.append("remove_directory_chunks",'<?php echo $directory_name?>');
                                    fd.append('action','remove_chunks');
                                    fetch('<?php echo APP_URL?>save.php',{method:"POST",body:fd})
                                    .then(chunks_response => chunks_response.json())
                                    .then(chunk_res =>{
                                      console.log('get back chunks response '+chunk_res);
                                        if(chunk_res.message = 'Chunks Remove Successfully')
                                        {
                                            var timer_status = document.getElementById("tiles").innerHTML;
                                            if(timer_status == "EXPIRED")
                                            {
                                                $.ajax({
                                                    type: "post",
                                                    url:  "<?php echo API_URL; ?>api/TestSubmitted",
                                                    data: {submit:'yes',userId:"<?php echo $user_id ?>",scheduleId:"<?php echo $scheduleid ?>"},
                                                    success: function (response) {
                                                        swal({
                                                            title: "Time Expires",
                                                            text: 'Please wait we are saving your score',
                                                            icon: 'success',
                                                            buttons: false,
                                                            timer: 15000
                                                        }).then(function() {
                                                            window.location="<?php echo APP_URL;?>thank.php";
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }else{
                                                $.ajax({
                                                    type: "post",
                                                    url:  '<?php echo API_URL; ?>api/TestSubmitted',
                                                    data: {submit:'yes',userId:"<?php echo $user_id ?>",scheduleId:"<?php echo $scheduleid ?>"},
                                                    success: function (response) {
                                                        swal({
                                                            title: "Completed",
                                                            text: 'Please wait we are saving your score',
                                                            icon: 'success',
                                                            buttons: false,
                                                            timer: 15000
                                                        }).then(function() {
                                                            window.location="<?php echo APP_URL;?>thank.php";
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .catch(err => console.log('chunks error response '+err));
                                }
                            })
                            .catch(err => console.log('data response '+err));
                        });
                    }
                    
                    // stopBtn.disabled = false;
                }else{
                    console.log("localStream is missing");
                }

                // end start button functionality

                // start camera recording
                    cameraStream()
                    .then((data) => {})
                    .then(() => {});

                    console.log('data value '+ data);

                // end camera recording    

                }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "You need a microphone to run the demo";
                });
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                alert('you need to share your entire screen with auido to start your task. Thanks');
                location.reload();
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "You need to share your screen to run the demo";
            });
        }

        async function cameraStream() 
        {
            try {
                camera_stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
            }
            catch(error) {
                alert(error.message);
                return;
            }

            video.srcObject = camera_stream;

            if(camera_stream != null)
            {
                media_recorder = new MediaRecorder(camera_stream);

                media_recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', function(e) {
                    blobs_recorded.push(e.data);
                    console.log('blobs data ' + blobs_recorded.push(e.data));
                });
            }
        }

        function onBtnStopClicked()
        {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            
        }
```

Getting error to save and merge chunks after click on stop button. getting issue in video saving.